# Kivy: Bad interpretation of color in kivy launcher

Tags: python, kivy

I want to show color palette. Color are showed on monitor pc without problems. If I use kivy launcher, on display are shoved only next colors: `(255, 0, 0),(0, 255, 0), (0, 0, 255) and (255, 255, 0)`.

Example colors, which aren't showed: `(255, 0, 255),(206, 105, 4), (247, 98, 236), (158, 133, 211)`.

Script for conversion to fraction of 1:

```
n = 1
for rgb in col:
   r = round(rgb[0]/255,n)
   g = round(rgb[1]/255,n)
   b = round(rgb[2]/255,n)
   self.liCol.append((r, g, b))
```

Comment: In script for conversion is bad value of divisor. Right value is 255.0

Comment: then why you are using 255 ? it did not work with 255.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment it sounds like you've resolved the issue, but to be explicit about it: in python2 `/` performs integer division if applied to integers, which returns 0 in all your examples. Changing `255` to `255.0` makes sure python performs the float division you want.